# How to overcome forbidden error in downloading restassured JAR's?

Tags: rest-assured

I was trying to download the restassured JAR's from resassured.io with all dependencies but it keeps on giving forbiddn error. From rest-assured site, it navigates to github and from there http://dl.bintray.com/ and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Later, i realized that these are available in maven repository so downloaded from there.

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=restassured

As this could be helpful to all beginners hence sharing.